# SQL - How to convert a varchar into int with case

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
productId Inventory 
--------------------    
1            1
2            Ab
3            12.5
4            6
6            2
```

How to select inventory as `int` and other value is zero, where `Inventory` is `varchar`?

Comment: exactly what int would you assign to 'ab' or 12.5?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is SQL Server, then you can do this:

```
SELECT productid, 
  CAST((CASE isnumeric(inventory) 
          WHEN 0 THEN 0 
          ELSE CAST(Inventory AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
        END) AS INT) AS Inventory 
FROM tablename
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/378c2/10)

This will give you:

```
| PRODUCTID | INVENTORY |
-------------------------
|         1 |         1 |
|         2 |         0 |
|         3 |        12 |
|         4 |         6 |
|         6 |         2 |
```

Comment: Hi This given me all decimal result , how to convert in int

Answer (score 2):

If you want decimal values like 12.5 to come out as ints and not decimals, you'd have to do something like the following to trim the decimal places:

```
select case when isNumeric(Inventory) = 1 then cast(cast(Inventory as DECIMAL(10,0)) as INT) else 0 end as Inventory_INT, productId
from PRODUCTS
```

Comment: If it helped a +1 would be nice :)

Comment: `Isnumeric()` cannot be used to check numeric values as such in sql server. This won't solve your problem. Even `isnumeric(',') = 1`. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9397)

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when isnumeric(inventory) then
       cast(inventory as INT)
else
       0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are much safer to use `PatIndex()`. *IsNumeric* is not the best way to check for numeric values in sql-server because it will return 1 for currency symbols as well (ex, `isnumerc('$')` *equals* to 1) [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186272.aspx).

Following example is not rounding up decimal values. If you need to rounded up values then convert inventory to decimal. [Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e48a/7) Using `Patindex()` function.

```
select productId, case patindex('%[0-9]%',inventory) 
                  when 1 then convert(int,convert(decimal(10,2),inventory))
                  else 0 end inventory
from T


| PRODUCTID | INVENTORY |
-------------------------
|         1 |         1 |
|         2 |         0 |
|         3 |        12 |--NOTE
|         4 |         6 |
|         6 |         2 |
|         7 |         0 |--Extra data row added with '$'
```

To get the rounded up values from inventory;

```
select productId, case patindex('%[0-9]%',inventory) 
                  when 1 then convert(decimal,inventory)
                  else 0 end inventory
from T

| PRODUCTID | INVENTORY |
-------------------------
|         1 |         1 |
|         2 |         0 |
|         3 |        13 |--NOTE
|         4 |         6 |
|         6 |         2 |
|         7 |         0 |--Extra data row added with '$'
```

Comment: Hi Yes Kaf . Thanks for provide me solution

Comment: No problem, are you on sql server?